# Matomo: Is it possible to show the ratio/share of events?

Tags: analytics, tracking, matomo

Starting point: A user can click on button A or button B.

The question: Can I see or track in Matomo how many users have clicked button A vs how many users have clicked button B?

Can Matomo display such relations at all?